Makefile take short file name and find/process full file name
All of our .tex files are of a form:
Proj-JIRA-1234-Internal.tex

(where 1234 can be any 4-digit number.)
I currently have the command to process the full filename like this:
%: %.tex
    echo $@
    texify --pdf --synctex=1 --clean $@.tex

I was wondering if there was a way I could call make like:
make 1234.tex
And it could find the full filename and execute the texify  command.
I'm kind of new to Makefile so I don't know if this is doable.
I tried changing some of the parameters, and was getting circular references, etc. I am also playing around with some of the string functions available within Make but they appear to work on the file name as it exists in the repo?

Is the filename always of the form Proj-JIRA-<X>-Internal.tex where you want to run make <X> to have it created?

It's generally a pretty bad idea to have "match anything" rules like % : %.tex.  This tells make that it can potentially build ANY file from a file named xxx.tex, which means make has to check a LOT of possibilities.  What is it that you really want this rule to do?  Does it really have to build a file named XXX when it processes a file named XXX.tex?  Is there any other common parts to the XXX?

The files are always of the form there, yes.
We will only be building the files that match the form, what I was trying to do, was to make it easier for someone to make the individual file, if they could just use the Jira number, and have the rest of the filename expanded from that, and sent to the command. From what I'm seeing, this may not be easily done?

make 1234.tex implies that make will be trying to make the target 1234.tex, when in fact it looks like you're trying to create the non-.tex version of the file.   You could do something along the lines of:
make NUM=1234

# NUM should be first target in makefile to make it the default target:
$(NUM) : Proj-JIRA-%-Internal
.PHONY: $(NUM)

Proj-JIRA-%-Internal : Proj-JIRA-%-Internal.tex
    @echo Building $@
    texify --pdf --synctex=1 --clean $@.tex

Alternatively you could create the makefile:
make 1234

% : Proj-JIRA-%-Internal

Proj-JIRA-%-Internal : Proj-JIRA-%-Internal.tex
    @echo Building $@
    texify --pdf --synctex=1 --clean $@.tex

But this runs into the problem that @MadScientist mentioned that you have a match-anything rule.
Finally, and likely the most 'correct' solution would be to do a wrapper script (you typically don't want to do editing on target names being passed into make).
textify.sh 1234

#!/bin/bash
make Proj-JIRA-$1-Internal

Proj-JIRA-%-Internal : Proj-JIRA-%-Internal.tex
    @echo Building $@
    texify --pdf --synctex=1 --clean $@.tex


Yeah I was thinking about this method. I was hoping that I'd be able to do it easily in Make, but I understand what is being said. I'll look at the shell script version.

A much easier solution is to create a shell function (or alias; but aliases suck)
mktx () {
    local i
    for i; do
        make Proj-JIRA-"$i"-Internal.tex
    done
}

If you have Bash 5.2+ you can put them all in at the same time:
mktx () {
    local a=("$@")
    make "${a[@]/*/Proj-JIRA-&-Internal.tex}"
}

(The same transformation can be done with more code in older versions. Prefix and postfix elements of a bash array)

You can avoid the match-anything issue with something like this:
JIRAS := $(patsubst Proj-JIRA-%-Internal.tex,%,$(wildcard Proj-JIRA-*-Internal.tex))

all: $(JIRAS)

$(JIRAS) : % : Proj-JIRA-%-Internal ;

The first line computes all the JIRA issue IDs from the existing .tex files, and the third line is a static pattern rule that maps each JIRA issue ID to depend on the target file.  Then use the pattern rule suggested by HardcoreHenry to build the results:
Proj-JIRA-%-Internal : Proj-JIRA-%-Internal.tex
        @echo Building $@
        texify --pdf --synctex=1 --clean $<

This of course assumes that the .tex exist before you run make; if these files are also generated by the makefile this won't work.
